# Notification bar text? using Coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

How can read the Notification bar text using Coded UI. I record the notification bar and Notification text, but i am unable to read the text of notification bar, making Draw Highlighting the Notification text, but unable to read the text, is it possible to read the text?

```
[GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "12.0.31101.0")]
public class UINotificationToolBar : WinToolBar
{

    public UINotificationToolBar(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[WinToolBar.PropertyNames.Name] = "Notification";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Send with Options");
        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties
    public WinText NotificationbarTextText
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mNotificationbarTextText == null))
            {
                this.mNotificationbarTextText = new WinText(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mNotificationbarTextText.SearchProperties[WinText.PropertyNames.Name] = "Notification bar Text";
                this.mNotificationbarTextText.WindowTitles.Add("Send with Options");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mNotificationbarTextText;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private WinText mNotificationbarTextText;
    #endregion
}
```

The control is Window Contrls

Comment: This is my code:

           toolBar.NotificationbarTextText.Find();
           string s =  toolBar.NotificationbarTextText.DisplayText.ToString();

but it is returning null

Comment: You can use the inspector from record and play option to navigate down the control tree until you land on the control with the text you want to capture.  Turn on record and play, put the mouse over the nofitication bar, press Ctrl + Shift + I (capital i).  This will select the notification bar.  Then, at the top of the control panel is a control navigation icon with up, right, down, and left arrows.  This will let you move around until you find the control that actually has the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted nearly enough code for us to answer this correctly. What type of control is toolBar? Why are you using hungarian notation for NotificationbarTextText?

However, you may want to try:

```
toolBar.NotificationbarTextText.InnerText.ToString();
```

rather than:

```
toolBar.NotificationbarTextText.DisplayText.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Ryanman, Thanks for reply, I tried u r code also, even thought it is returning null. i paste my code, i mean  what i recorded for Notification Text

Comment: Surya,

I was incorrect regarding DisplayText vs InnerText. You should view the UI map for the Notification bar object. The element you're trying to get the text of may be a child of the WinText object. If you're identifying the control correctly, there's no reason you should not be able to get the display text.